# Bootstrap span issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a little vCard using twitter as a bootstrap and I encountered a small issue that I'm not able to track it's source :)

If you follow this link : [Demo](http://labs.rolandgroza.me/roland/) ; you will see that elements are kind of messed up :) In the header of the vCard the contact information should be on the right of the name and thumb, but it's pushed underneath. The same goes for the small description :)

Using `row-fluid` instead of just `row` will fix that, but because my mobile version needs not to be fluid I cannot use the fluid grid. I hope someone encountered this issue before and has an idea what is the source of it :)

Comment: for me, its pushed underneath because it takes to much place. In `contact-details-container`, try to change your font size to a smaller size just to check the result. And the small description is pushed down because `contact-details-container` is pushed down.

Comment: @lemoisela ~ I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working, I still have the same issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make it work nice on mobile devices, you should really consider the css properties of the class `content-view-container`: you have absolute positioning and fixed-value width that don't play well when you want to design for "any" screen size...

There are some issues in the code:

- first of all the `span2` and `span12` shouldn't be "pulled-left" (there is also a typo in the class name) and "pulled-right" (it makes useless the meaning of "grid"...)
- all the style of `info-button-container` are redundant (just keep the `margin-top`)
- in `info-button-inner` why are you using `border-box` property? to fix the position of the icon in the middle play with the `line-height` attribute
- why setting all the `div`s as `position:relative; display: block;`? no use here...
- `row` doesn't need the class `clearfix` as it is already "clearfixed"

Comment: I mistakenly added the floating on the spans :) The style on the `info-button-container` it's needed, at least the index, and dimension properties :) As for the inner, the icon cannot be positioned with `line-height`, only if I use `display: inline-block;` which isn't supported in all the browsers, especially IE :) So I had to position it by using the `box-sizing` property and some padding :) Some of the divs do need the positioning and the display because there are certain elements added with the pseudo elements `:after` & `:before` that need the parent element to have a position :)

Comment: but it's exactly those modifications to the framework structure that are breaking the layout